# Use date values from different sheet in formula

Tags: excel, date

I have two sheets in my excel file.
The first sheet contains values and dates, on the second I want to calculate values between a date range.

for instance:
50      20/9/2014
1600    16/10/2014
254     21/10/2014
1547    03/11/2014

(Belgian time)

I tried this with the following formula:

```
=SUMIFS(INPUT!$G$3:$G$100; INPUT!$H$3:$H$27; ">=01/10/2014"; INPUT!$H$3:$H$27; "<=31/10/2014")
```

This gives me an error in the formula and I notice that inside the formula values the date has become a random value:

[image]

Anyone has an idea how to do this correctly?

Comment: It should work. Are your references correct? What is your exact error?  (I'm also Belgian)

Comment: It is just returning #VALUE! in the cell.. thought it had something to do with the date turning into a value as formula criteria

Comment: Same error.. could it have something to do with the used date format?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/731875-sumifs-returns-value.html). They say because your ranges aren't the same size. I tried it and received the same error. Could you try it with criteria that's the same size?

Comment: lol that did it! ranges must be exact the same size. Make it an answer and I'll accept it ;) thx man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find it at first either, but it seems your ranges need to be the same size `(sum_range and criteria)`.

So change your sum_range to `G3:G37` or your criteria range to `H3:H100` and it will solve your problem. :)

Reference: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/731875-sumifs-returns-value.html